# does python convert audio data to file?

Tags: javascript, python, upload, decode, wav

I want to send my audio data and create audio file.
I don't know how to decode and write audio data

Below code are python flask code and javascript.
index.html contain voice.js and fetch.js to send audio data.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/<name>.js")
def getJs(name):
    return render_template(name+'.js')

@app.route("/audio", methods=['post'])
def audio():
    f = open('temp.webm','+wb')
    f.write(request.data)
    f.close()

    return make_response('', 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

voice.js

```
const voice = [];

navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
    })
    .then((mediaStream) => {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
            // mimeType: 'audio/webm; codecs="pcm"',
            // audioBitsPerSecond: 16000,
        });

        mediaRecorder.start(1000)

        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (e) => {
            voice.push(e.data);
        });
    })
```

fetch.js

```
setInterval(() => {
    if (voice.length > 1) {
        let blob = voice.shift()
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/audio', {
            method: 'post',
            body: blob
        })
        
        console.log(blob)
    }

}, 1000)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="result">result</p>
</body>
<script src="voice.js"></script>
<script src="fetch.js"></script>
</html>
```

I want to create a new audio file(ex 'voice.wav').
audio data as 'temp.wdbm' file does not play any sound. an error occured while loading 'temp.webm' file with media player.

Answer (score 0):

You are already saving audio data as a ".webm" file. If you want to save the audio as a ".wav" file, use the "pydub" library as follows:

1. First, install "pydub":

```
pip install pydub
```

2. Modify your "server.py" file:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

@app.route("/audio", methods=['post'])
def audio():
    temp_filename = 'temp.webm'
    with open(temp_filename, '+wb') as f:
        f.write(request.data)
    
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(temp_filename, format="webm")
    output_filename = 'voice.wav'
    audio.export(output_filename, format="wav")
    
    return make_response('', 200)
    return make_response('', 200)
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: already saving audio data as ".wdbm" file does not play any sound. 
an error occured while loading 'temp.webm' file with media player